# How to connect ambassador to ssl enabled google instance groups

Tags: ssl

We are connecting Ambassador (API Gateway - https://www.getambassador.io/) to Google VM instance group via a load balancer where in http/2 is enabled. This requires ssl must be enabled. There is no proper information on how to connect Ambassador to an SSL enabled end system.

We tried connecting to Google VM instance from an Ambassador pod which is running in kubernetes via normal http service as per the suggestion - https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues/585. But could not find a way to connect to an SSL enabled endpoint by providing SSL certificate.

```
 kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: a-b-service
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  a-b-mapping
      grpc: True
      headers:
        lang: t
      prefix: /a.Listener/
      rewrite: /a.Listener/
      service: http://<ip>:<port>/
      timeout_ms: 60000
```

We want to connect to an SSL enabled Google VM instance group via loadbalancing. Also, how to provide SSL certificate to this

```
    kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: a-b-service
  annotations:
.....
      service: https://<ip>:443/     <---- https with ssl
      timeout_ms: 60000
```

Can someone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ambassador has a fair amount of documentation around TLS, so probably your best bet is to check out https://www.getambassador.io/reference/core/tls/ and start from there.

The short version is specifying a `service` that starts with `https://` is enough for Ambassador to originate TLS, but if you want to control the originating certificate, you need to reference a `TLSContext` as well.